# (MySQL 8/Win10) Error 1114: Temp Table Out of Space- But Strange Oddity?

Tags: mysql

I have:

- MySQL 8.0.25 New/Clean Re-Install (using mainly HeidiSQL, but also Command Line at times)
- Windows 10 (dedicated MySQL machine)
- 128GB Ram
- Separate SSD for both OS and Data Drives
- Temp DIR pointing to Data Drive w/ 600GB free space
- 82Mil+ rows of data I'm querying, about 18GB in size

The Error I'm getting: (or variation on the actual file name each time)
SQL Error (1114): The table 'D:\Temp#sql1708_8_30' is full

These Variables have been set:

```
- @@innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:12M:autoextend
- @@max_heap_table_size=68719476736
- @@tmp_table_size=80530636800
- @@tmpdir=D:/Temp
```

*BIG LIST OF ALL VARIABLES DOWN BELOW*

**DETAILS:**

I've spent over a week trying to get various queries to run, and have minimized/optimized as much as I can, but still getting this error. I've tried every answer on Reddit/Stack/Forums (they all point to the variables I listed above, more or less) and NOTHING is working.

**One Oddity:**

In my Windows Processes, I have listed a MySQL, and a MySQL80. The 1st one is turned off. I have searched multiple times, and there's only ONE 'my.ini' file anywhere on my computer. HOWEVER- I get discrepancies from when I SELECT the variables above inside HeidiSQL and the Command Line...

ie:

```
-HeidiSQL: @@max_heap_table_size = 68719476736

-Command Line: @@max_heap_table_size = 104857600
```

Same results with the tmp_table_size.

Why would I be getting different variable settings depending on where I'm pulling it from? There's no way I'm out of disk space as I have 600gb+ free on 64-bit Win10. I have PLENTY of ram I would think- and the settings in the variables should be more than enough to suffice. I'd REALLY appreciate any help you can give!

Here's a list of ALL my variables:

```
"Variable_name" "Value"
"activate_all_roles_on_login"   "OFF"
"admin_address" ""
"admin_port"    "33062"
"admin_ssl_ca"  ""
"admin_ssl_capath"  ""
"admin_ssl_cert"    ""
"admin_ssl_cipher"  ""
"admin_ssl_crl" ""
"admin_ssl_crlpath" ""
"admin_ssl_key" ""
"admin_tls_ciphersuites"    ""
"admin_tls_version" "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"
"auto_generate_certs"   "ON"
"auto_increment_increment"  "1"
"auto_increment_offset" "1"
"autocommit"    "ON"
"automatic_sp_privileges"   "ON"
"avoid_temporal_upgrade"    "OFF"
"back_log"  "80"
"basedir"   "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\"
"big_tables"    "OFF"
"bind_address"  "*"
"binlog_cache_size" "32768"
"binlog_checksum"   "CRC32"
"binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates"   "OFF"
"binlog_encryption" "OFF"
"binlog_error_action"   "ABORT_SERVER"
"binlog_expire_logs_seconds"    "2592000"
"binlog_format" "ROW"
"binlog_group_commit_sync_delay"    "0"
"binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count"   "0"
"binlog_gtid_simple_recovery"   "ON"
"binlog_max_flush_queue_time"   "0"
"binlog_order_commits"  "ON"
"binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup"    "OFF"
"binlog_row_event_max_size" "8192"
"binlog_row_image"  "FULL"
"binlog_row_metadata"   "MINIMAL"
"binlog_row_value_options"  ""
"binlog_rows_query_log_events"  "OFF"
"binlog_stmt_cache_size"    "32768"
"binlog_transaction_compression"    "OFF"
"binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd" "3"
"binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size"    "25000"
"binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking"    "COMMIT_ORDER"
"block_encryption_mode" "aes-128-ecb"
"bulk_insert_buffer_size"   "8388608"
"caching_sha2_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys"  "ON"
"caching_sha2_password_digest_rounds"   "5000"
"caching_sha2_password_private_key_path"    "private_key.pem"
"caching_sha2_password_public_key_path" "public_key.pem"
"character_set_client"  "utf8mb4"
"character_set_connection"  "utf8mb4"
"character_set_database"    "utf8mb4"
"character_set_filesystem"  "binary"
"character_set_results" "utf8mb4"
"character_set_server"  "utf8mb4"
"character_set_system"  "utf8mb3"
"character_sets_dir"    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\"
"check_proxy_users" "OFF"
"collation_connection"  "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"
"collation_database"    "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"
"collation_server"  "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"
"completion_type"   "NO_CHAIN"
"concurrent_insert" "AUTO"
"connect_timeout"   "10"
"core_file" "OFF"
"create_admin_listener_thread"  "OFF"
"cte_max_recursion_depth"   "1000"
"datadir"   "D:\Data\"
"default_authentication_plugin" "caching_sha2_password"
"default_collation_for_utf8mb4" "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"
"default_password_lifetime" "0"
"default_storage_engine"    "InnoDB"
"default_table_encryption"  "OFF"
"default_tmp_storage_engine"    "InnoDB"
"default_week_format"   "0"
"delay_key_write"   "ON"
"delayed_insert_limit"  "100"
"delayed_insert_timeout"    "300"
"delayed_queue_size"    "1000"
"disabled_storage_engines"  ""
"disconnect_on_expired_password"    "ON"
"div_precision_increment"   "4"
"end_markers_in_json"   "OFF"
"enforce_gtid_consistency"  "OFF"
"eq_range_index_dive_limit" "200"
"error_count"   "0"
"event_scheduler"   "ON"
"expire_logs_days"  "0"
"explicit_defaults_for_timestamp"   "ON"
"external_user" ""
"flush" "OFF"
"flush_time"    "0"
"foreign_key_checks"    "ON"
"ft_boolean_syntax" "+ -><()~*:""""&|"
"ft_max_word_len"   "84"
"ft_min_word_len"   "4"
"ft_query_expansion_limit"  "20"
"ft_stopword_file"  "(built-in)"
"general_log"   "OFF"
"general_log_file"  "KITT.log"
"generated_random_password_length"  "20"
"group_concat_max_len"  "1024"
"group_replication_consistency" "EVENTUAL"
"gtid_executed" ""
"gtid_executed_compression_period"  "0"
"gtid_mode" "OFF"
"gtid_next" "AUTOMATIC"
"gtid_owned"    ""
"gtid_purged"   ""
"have_compress" "YES"
"have_dynamic_loading"  "YES"
"have_geometry" "YES"
"have_openssl"  "YES"
"have_profiling"    "YES"
"have_query_cache"  "NO"
"have_rtree_keys"   "YES"
"have_ssl"  "YES"
"have_statement_timeout"    "YES"
"have_symlink"  "DISABLED"
"histogram_generation_max_mem_size" "20000000"
"host_cache_size"   "279"
"hostname"  "KITT"
"identity"  "1"
"immediate_server_version"  "999999"
"information_schema_stats_expiry"   "86400"
"init_connect"  ""
"init_file" ""
"init_slave"    ""
"innodb_adaptive_flushing"  "ON"
"innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm"  "10"
"innodb_adaptive_hash_index"    "ON"
"innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts"  "8"
"innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay"   "150000"
"innodb_api_bk_commit_interval" "5"
"innodb_api_disable_rowlock"    "OFF"
"innodb_api_enable_binlog"  "OFF"
"innodb_api_enable_mdl" "OFF"
"innodb_api_trx_level"  "0"
"innodb_autoextend_increment"   "1000"
"innodb_autoinc_lock_mode"  "2"
"innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size" "134217728"
"innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown"   "ON"
"innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now"   "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct"   "25"
"innodb_buffer_pool_filename"   "ib_buffer_pool"
"innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file"   "ON"
"innodb_buffer_pool_instances"  "40"
"innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort" "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup"    "ON"
"innodb_buffer_pool_load_now"   "OFF"
"innodb_buffer_pool_size"   "69793218560"
"innodb_change_buffer_max_size" "25"
"innodb_change_buffering"   "all"
"innodb_checksum_algorithm" "crc32"
"innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled"  "OFF"
"innodb_commit_concurrency" "0"
"innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct"  "5"
"innodb_compression_level"  "6"
"innodb_compression_pad_pct_max"    "50"
"innodb_concurrency_tickets"    "5000"
"innodb_data_file_path" "ibdata1:12M:autoextend"
"innodb_data_home_dir"  ""
"innodb_deadlock_detect"    "ON"
"innodb_dedicated_server"   "OFF"
"innodb_default_row_format" "dynamic"
"innodb_directories"    ""
"innodb_disable_sort_file_cache"    "OFF"
"innodb_doublewrite"    "ON"
"innodb_doublewrite_batch_size" "0"
"innodb_doublewrite_dir"    ""
"innodb_doublewrite_files"  "2"
"innodb_doublewrite_pages"  "4"
"innodb_extend_and_initialize"  "ON"
"innodb_fast_shutdown"  "1"
"innodb_file_per_table" "ON"
"innodb_fill_factor"    "100"
"innodb_flush_log_at_timeout"   "1"
"innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit"    "1"
"innodb_flush_method"   "unbuffered"
"innodb_flush_neighbors"    "0"
"innodb_flush_sync" "ON"
"innodb_flushing_avg_loops" "30"
"innodb_force_load_corrupted"   "OFF"
"innodb_force_recovery" "0"
"innodb_fsync_threshold"    "0"
"innodb_ft_aux_table"   ""
"innodb_ft_cache_size"  "8000000"
"innodb_ft_enable_diag_print"   "OFF"
"innodb_ft_enable_stopword" "ON"
"innodb_ft_max_token_size"  "84"
"innodb_ft_min_token_size"  "3"
"innodb_ft_num_word_optimize"   "2000"
"innodb_ft_result_cache_limit"  "2000000000"
"innodb_ft_server_stopword_table"   ""
"innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree" "2"
"innodb_ft_total_cache_size"    "640000000"
"innodb_ft_user_stopword_table" ""
"innodb_idle_flush_pct" "100"
"innodb_io_capacity"    "200"
"innodb_io_capacity_max"    "2000"
"innodb_lock_wait_timeout"  "50"
"innodb_log_buffer_size"    "12582912"
"innodb_log_checksums"  "ON"
"innodb_log_compressed_pages"   "ON"
"innodb_log_file_size"  "50331648"
"innodb_log_files_in_group" "2"
"innodb_log_group_home_dir" ".\"
"innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm"   "80"
"innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm"   "50"
"innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm"    "400"
"innodb_log_write_ahead_size"   "8192"
"innodb_log_writer_threads" "ON"
"innodb_lru_scan_depth" "1024"
"innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct"    "90.000000"
"innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm"    "10.000000"
"innodb_max_purge_lag"  "0"
"innodb_max_purge_lag_delay"    "0"
"innodb_max_undo_log_size"  "1073741824"
"innodb_monitor_disable"    ""
"innodb_monitor_enable" ""
"innodb_monitor_reset"  ""
"innodb_monitor_reset_all"  ""
"innodb_old_blocks_pct" "37"
"innodb_old_blocks_time"    "1000"
"innodb_online_alter_log_max_size"  "134217728"
"innodb_open_files" "300"
"innodb_optimize_fulltext_only" "OFF"
"innodb_page_cleaners"  "4"
"innodb_page_size"  "16384"
"innodb_parallel_read_threads"  "4"
"innodb_print_all_deadlocks"    "OFF"
"innodb_print_ddl_logs" "OFF"
"innodb_purge_batch_size"   "300"
"innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency"  "128"
"innodb_purge_threads"  "4"
"innodb_random_read_ahead"  "OFF"
"innodb_read_ahead_threshold"   "56"
"innodb_read_io_threads"    "4"
"innodb_read_only"  "OFF"
"innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs"  ""
"innodb_redo_log_encrypt"   "OFF"
"innodb_replication_delay"  "0"
"innodb_rollback_on_timeout"    "OFF"
"innodb_rollback_segments"  "128"
"innodb_sort_buffer_size"   "1048576"
"innodb_spin_wait_delay"    "6"
"innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier" "50"
"innodb_stats_auto_recalc"  "ON"
"innodb_stats_include_delete_marked"    "OFF"
"innodb_stats_method"   "nulls_equal"
"innodb_stats_on_metadata"  "OFF"
"innodb_stats_persistent"   "ON"
"innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages"  "20"
"innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages"   "8"
"innodb_status_output"  "OFF"
"innodb_status_output_locks"    "OFF"
"innodb_strict_mode"    "ON"
"innodb_sync_array_size"    "1"
"innodb_sync_spin_loops"    "30"
"innodb_table_locks"    "ON"
"innodb_temp_data_file_path"    "ibtmp1:12M:autoextend"
"innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir"   ".\#innodb_temp\"
"innodb_thread_concurrency" "25"
"innodb_thread_sleep_delay" "0"
"innodb_tmpdir" ""
"innodb_undo_directory" ".\"
"innodb_undo_log_encrypt"   "OFF"
"innodb_undo_log_truncate"  "ON"
"innodb_undo_tablespaces"   "2"
"innodb_use_native_aio" "ON"
"innodb_validate_tablespace_paths"  "ON"
"innodb_version"    "8.0.25"
"innodb_write_io_threads"   "4"
"insert_id" "0"
"interactive_timeout"   "28800"
"internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine"   "TempTable"
"join_buffer_size"  "1048576"
"keep_files_on_create"  "OFF"
"key_buffer_size"   "22020096"
"key_cache_age_threshold"   "300"
"key_cache_block_size"  "1024"
"key_cache_division_limit"  "100"
"keyring_operations"    "ON"
"large_files_support"   "ON"
"large_page_size"   "0"
"large_pages"   "OFF"
"last_insert_id"    "1"
"lc_messages"   "en_US"
"lc_messages_dir"   "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\"
"lc_time_names" "en_US"
"license"   "GPL"
"local_infile"  "OFF"
"lock_wait_timeout" "31536000"
"log_bin"   "ON"
"log_bin_basename"  "D:\Data\KITT-bin"
"log_bin_index" "D:\Data\KITT-bin.index"
"log_bin_trust_function_creators"   "OFF"
"log_bin_use_v1_row_events" "OFF"
"log_error" ".\KITT.err"
"log_error_services"    "log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal"
"log_error_suppression_list"    ""
"log_error_verbosity"   "2"
"log_output"    "FILE"
"log_queries_not_using_indexes" "OFF"
"log_raw"   "OFF"
"log_slave_updates" "ON"
"log_slow_admin_statements" "OFF"
"log_slow_extra"    "OFF"
"log_slow_slave_statements" "OFF"
"log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog"  "ON"
"log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes"    "0"
"log_timestamps"    "UTC"
"long_query_time"   "10.000000"
"low_priority_updates"  "OFF"
"lower_case_file_system"    "ON"
"lower_case_table_names"    "1"
"mandatory_roles"   ""
"master_info_repository"    "TABLE"
"master_verify_checksum"    "OFF"
"max_allowed_packet"    "4194304"
"max_binlog_cache_size" "18446744073709547520"
"max_binlog_size"   "1073741824"
"max_binlog_stmt_cache_size"    "18446744073709547520"
"max_connect_errors"    "100"
"max_connections"   "151"
"max_delayed_threads"   "20"
"max_digest_length" "1024"
"max_error_count"   "1024"
"max_execution_time"    "0"
"max_heap_table_size"   "68719476736"
"max_insert_delayed_threads"    "20"
"max_join_size" "18446744073709551615"
"max_length_for_sort_data"  "4096"
"max_points_in_geometry"    "65536"
"max_prepared_stmt_count"   "16382"
"max_relay_log_size"    "0"
"max_seeks_for_key" "4294967295"
"max_sort_length"   "1024"
"max_sp_recursion_depth"    "0"
"max_user_connections"  "0"
"max_write_lock_count"  "4294967295"
"min_examined_row_limit"    "0"
"myisam_data_pointer_size"  "6"
"myisam_max_sort_file_size" "107374182400"
"myisam_mmap_size"  "18446744073709551615"
"myisam_recover_options"    "OFF"
"myisam_repair_threads" "1"
"myisam_sort_buffer_size"   "24696061952"
"myisam_stats_method"   "nulls_unequal"
"myisam_use_mmap"   "OFF"
"mysql_native_password_proxy_users" "OFF"
"mysqlx_bind_address"   "*"
"mysqlx_compression_algorithms" "DEFLATE_STREAM,LZ4_MESSAGE,ZSTD_STREAM"
"mysqlx_connect_timeout"    "30"
"mysqlx_deflate_default_compression_level"  "3"
"mysqlx_deflate_max_client_compression_level"   "5"
"mysqlx_document_id_unique_prefix"  "0"
"mysqlx_enable_hello_notice"    "ON"
"mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout" "60"
"mysqlx_interactive_timeout"    "28800"
"mysqlx_lz4_default_compression_level"  "2"
"mysqlx_lz4_max_client_compression_level"   "8"
"mysqlx_max_allowed_packet" "67108864"
"mysqlx_max_connections"    "100"
"mysqlx_min_worker_threads" "2"
"mysqlx_port"   "33060"
"mysqlx_port_open_timeout"  "0"
"mysqlx_read_timeout"   "30"
"mysqlx_socket" "/tmp/mysqlx.sock"
"mysqlx_ssl_ca" ""
"mysqlx_ssl_capath" ""
"mysqlx_ssl_cert"   ""
"mysqlx_ssl_cipher" ""
"mysqlx_ssl_crl"    ""
"mysqlx_ssl_crlpath"    ""
"mysqlx_ssl_key"    ""
"mysqlx_wait_timeout"   "28800"
"mysqlx_write_timeout"  "60"
"mysqlx_zstd_default_compression_level" "3"
"mysqlx_zstd_max_client_compression_level"  "11"
"named_pipe"    "OFF"
"named_pipe_full_access_group"  ""
"net_buffer_length" "16384"
"net_read_timeout"  "30"
"net_retry_count"   "10"
"net_write_timeout" "60"
"new"   "OFF"
"ngram_token_size"  "2"
"offline_mode"  "OFF"
"old"   "OFF"
"old_alter_table"   "OFF"
"open_files_limit"  "6209"
"optimizer_prune_level" "1"
"optimizer_search_depth"    "62"
"optimizer_switch"  "index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,use_invisible_indexes=off,skip_scan=on,hash_join=on,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=on,hypergraph_optimizer=off,derived_condition_pushdown=on"
"optimizer_trace"   "enabled=off,one_line=off"
"optimizer_trace_features"  "greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on"
"optimizer_trace_limit" "1"
"optimizer_trace_max_mem_size"  "1048576"
"optimizer_trace_offset"    "-1"
"original_commit_timestamp" "36028797018963968"
"original_server_version"   "999999"
"parser_max_mem_size"   "18446744073709551615"
"partial_revokes"   "OFF"
"password_history"  "0"
"password_require_current"  "OFF"
"password_reuse_interval"   "0"
"performance_schema"    "ON"
"performance_schema_accounts_size"  "-1"
"performance_schema_digests_size"   "10000"
"performance_schema_error_size" "4890"
"performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size"    "10000"
"performance_schema_events_stages_history_size" "10"
"performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size"    "10000"
"performance_schema_events_statements_history_size" "10"
"performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size"  "10000"
"performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size"   "10"
"performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size" "10000"
"performance_schema_events_waits_history_size"  "10"
"performance_schema_hosts_size" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_cond_classes"   "100"
"performance_schema_max_cond_instances" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_digest_length"  "1024"
"performance_schema_max_digest_sample_age"  "60"
"performance_schema_max_file_classes"   "80"
"performance_schema_max_file_handles"   "32768"
"performance_schema_max_file_instances" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_index_stat" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_memory_classes" "450"
"performance_schema_max_metadata_locks" "-1"
"performance_schema_max_mutex_classes"  "300"
"performance_schema_max_mutex_instances"    "-1"
"performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances"  "-1"
"performance_schema_max_program_instances"  "-1"
"performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes" "60"
"performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances"   "-1"
"performance_schema_max_socket_classes" "10"
"performance_schema_max_socket_instances"   "-1"
"performance_schema_max_sql_text_length"    "1024"
"performance_schema_max_stage_classes"  "175"
"performance_schema_max_statement_classes"  "218"
"performance_schema_max_statement_stack"    "10"
"performance_schema_max_table_handles"  "-1"
"performance_schema_max_table_instances"    "-1"
"performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat"    "-1"
"performance_schema_max_thread_classes" "100"
"performance_schema_max_thread_instances"   "-1"
"performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size" "512"
"performance_schema_setup_actors_size"  "-1"
"performance_schema_setup_objects_size" "-1"
"performance_schema_show_processlist"   "OFF"
"performance_schema_users_size" "-1"
"persist_only_admin_x509_subject"   ""
"persisted_globals_load"    "ON"
"pid_file"  "D:\Data\KITT.pid"
"plugin_dir"    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\"
"port"  "3306"
"preload_buffer_size"   "32768"
"print_identified_with_as_hex"  "OFF"
"profiling" "OFF"
"profiling_history_size"    "15"
"protocol_compression_algorithms"   "zlib,zstd,uncompressed"
"protocol_version"  "10"
"proxy_user"    ""
"pseudo_slave_mode" "OFF"
"pseudo_thread_id"  "8"
"query_alloc_block_size"    "8192"
"query_prealloc_size"   "8192"
"rand_seed1"    "0"
"rand_seed2"    "0"
"range_alloc_block_size"    "4096"
"range_optimizer_max_mem_size"  "8388608"
"rbr_exec_mode" "STRICT"
"read_buffer_size"  "65536"
"read_only" "OFF"
"read_rnd_buffer_size"  "262144"
"regexp_stack_limit"    "8000000"
"regexp_time_limit" "32"
"relay_log" "KITT-relay-bin"
"relay_log_basename"    "D:\Data\KITT-relay-bin"
"relay_log_index"   "D:\Data\KITT-relay-bin.index"
"relay_log_info_file"   "relay-log.info"
"relay_log_info_repository" "TABLE"
"relay_log_purge"   "ON"
"relay_log_recovery"    "OFF"
"relay_log_space_limit" "0"
"replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config" "OFF"
"replication_sender_observe_commit_only"    "OFF"
"report_host"   ""
"report_password"   ""
"report_port"   "3306"
"report_user"   ""
"require_row_format"    "OFF"
"require_secure_transport"  "OFF"
"resultset_metadata"    "FULL"
"rpl_read_size" "8192"
"rpl_stop_slave_timeout"    "31536000"
"schema_definition_cache"   "256"
"secondary_engine_cost_threshold"   "100000.000000"
"secure_file_priv"  "D:\Uploads\"
"select_into_buffer_size"   "131072"
"select_into_disk_sync" "OFF"
"select_into_disk_sync_delay"   "0"
"server_id" "1"
"server_id_bits"    "32"
"server_uuid"   "61fadf29-6cb2-11eb-a9e0-2cf05d9715d6"
"session_track_gtids"   "OFF"
"session_track_schema"  "ON"
"session_track_state_change"    "OFF"
"session_track_system_variables"    "time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection"
"session_track_transaction_info"    "OFF"
"sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys"    "ON"
"sha256_password_private_key_path"  "private_key.pem"
"sha256_password_proxy_users"   "OFF"
"sha256_password_public_key_path"   "public_key.pem"
"shared_memory" "OFF"
"shared_memory_base_name"   "MYSQL"
"show_create_table_skip_secondary_engine"   "OFF"
"show_create_table_verbosity"   "OFF"
"show_old_temporals"    "OFF"
"skip_external_locking" "ON"
"skip_name_resolve" "OFF"
"skip_networking"   "OFF"
"skip_show_database"    "OFF"
"skip_slave_start"  "OFF"
"slave_allow_batching"  "OFF"
"slave_checkpoint_group"    "512"
"slave_checkpoint_period"   "300"
"slave_compressed_protocol" "OFF"
"slave_exec_mode"   "STRICT"
"slave_load_tmpdir" "D:\Temp"
"slave_max_allowed_packet"  "1073741824"
"slave_net_timeout" "60"
"slave_parallel_type"   "DATABASE"
"slave_parallel_workers"    "0"
"slave_pending_jobs_size_max"   "134217728"
"slave_preserve_commit_order"   "OFF"
"slave_rows_search_algorithms"  "INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN"
"slave_skip_errors" "OFF"
"slave_sql_verify_checksum" "ON"
"slave_transaction_retries" "10"
"slave_type_conversions"    ""
"slow_launch_time"  "2"
"slow_query_log"    "ON"
"slow_query_log_file"   "KITT-slow.log"
"socket"    "MySQL"
"sort_buffer_size"  "1048576"
"sql_auto_is_null"  "OFF"
"sql_big_selects"   "ON"
"sql_buffer_result" "OFF"
"sql_log_bin"   "ON"
"sql_log_off"   "OFF"
"sql_mode"  "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
"sql_notes" "ON"
"sql_quote_show_create" "ON"
"sql_require_primary_key"   "OFF"
"sql_safe_updates"  "OFF"
"sql_select_limit"  "18446744073709551615"
"sql_slave_skip_counter"    "0"
"sql_warnings"  "OFF"
"ssl_ca"    "ca.pem"
"ssl_capath"    ""
"ssl_cert"  "server-cert.pem"
"ssl_cipher"    ""
"ssl_crl"   ""
"ssl_crlpath"   ""
"ssl_fips_mode" "OFF"
"ssl_key"   "server-key.pem"
"stored_program_cache"  "256"
"stored_program_definition_cache"   "256"
"super_read_only"   "OFF"
"sync_binlog"   "1"
"sync_master_info"  "10000"
"sync_relay_log"    "10000"
"sync_relay_log_info"   "10000"
"system_time_zone"  "US Mountain Standard Time"
"table_definition_cache"    "1400"
"table_encryption_privilege_check"  "OFF"
"table_open_cache"  "2000"
"table_open_cache_instances"    "16"
"tablespace_definition_cache"   "256"
"temptable_max_mmap"    "1073741824"
"temptable_max_ram" "1073741824"
"temptable_use_mmap"    "ON"
"thread_cache_size" "10"
"thread_handling"   "one-thread-per-connection"
"thread_stack"  "286720"
"time_zone" "SYSTEM"
"timestamp" "1621978062.938807"
"tls_ciphersuites"  ""
"tls_version"   "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"
"tmp_table_size"    "80530636800"
"tmpdir"    "D:/Temp"
"transaction_alloc_block_size"  "8192"
"transaction_allow_batching"    "OFF"
"transaction_isolation" "REPEATABLE-READ"
"transaction_prealloc_size" "4096"
"transaction_read_only" "OFF"
"transaction_write_set_extraction"  "XXHASH64"
"unique_checks" "ON"
"updatable_views_with_limit"    "YES"
"use_secondary_engine"  "ON"
"version"   "8.0.25"
"version_comment"   "MySQL Community Server - GPL"
"version_compile_machine"   "x86_64"
"version_compile_os"    "Win64"
"version_compile_zlib"  "1.2.11"
"wait_timeout"  "28800"
"warning_count" "0"
"windowing_use_high_precision"  "ON"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- @@max_heap_table_size=68719476736
- @@tmp_table_size=80530636800
```

No!  Don't set those to any value bigger than 1% of RAM unless you have a specific rationale.

Comment: ok- awesome. Got that changed. Thank you!